# Displaying ant version shows unable to locate tools.jar

Tags: java, ant

I was trying out `ant -version` after installing ant and I get this:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\JRE\jre7\lib
\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
```

I have also installed JDK under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25` and JRE under `C:\Program Files\JRE\jre7`. I have also added jdk and ant bin path in the environmental path PATH. Not sure what else needs to be done!

Comment: What is the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`pointing to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your environment variables. `JAVA_HOME` must point to the `jdk` root, while Path must contain `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`. A `jre` does **not** contain **tools.jar**, so you have to point it to a `jdk`.

Don't forget to also check `%ANT_HOME%`, but since it's already looking for **tools.jar**, I assume it's already configured correctly.

Comment: OH! I was under the assumption that you actually dont need JAVA_HOME and you can directly give the path in PATH without giving %JAVA_HONE%. Eclipse worked fine with this though!!

Answer (score 3):

A JRE doesn't have a tools.jar, you need a JDK. Set your **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** variables, so that they point to a JDK, not a JRE.